# Please help, use of %echo argument

Tags: linux, unix, input, echo

I have this problem of how to use echo to supplement input and tell the program how many output to give.

Basically, I have the program logic sorted out, which is to randomly select a subset of x number from y inputs. My code is here:

The problem is, how can I forward the argc variable in the main argument to the program execution??

The context requires me to call: %echo A B C D E F G | Subset 2, which suppose to print 2 characters at random. But I can't do this, the number 2 seems cannot be forwarded inside here. And the call of %echo command does not seem to work as well. Anybody please help

```
int main(int argc){
RandomizedQueue<char> q;
char input;


while(cin.peek() != '\n'){
    cin >> input;
    q.enqueue(input);
}

for(int k = 0; k < argc; k++)
    cout << q.dequeue() << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: the class RandomizedQueue is pre-defined and is working properly. enqueue function add input to the queue in random order, dequeue function delete and output the queue memebers

Answer (score 0):

I think the % in `%echo` is not something you're supposed to type, but rather signifies the command prompt itself.  So you type this:

```
echo A B C D E F G | ./Subset 2
```

Assuming your program is named Subset and is in the current working directory.  Then, Subset will receive argc==2 and argv=={"./Subset", "2"}.  You'll need to declare main in the standard way (you're missing argv):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Once you do that, argv[1] will be "2" as a string (the program's first argument).  You can do something like this to convert it to an int:

```
int count = atoi(argv[1]);
```

You should read up on the declaration of main, because argc is not the argument as a number, it is the number of arguments.  And declaring main with argc but not argv is highly atypical.